# Sharing object between nodejs instances (high i/o)

Tags: node.js, memcached, socket.io, cluster-computing

Im building a nodejs/socket.io based game and Im trying to implement node clustering to take advantage on multicore machines ( few machines, each has few cores ). I figured out that memcache will be nice solution, but Im not completely sure if it'll survive high load, because each game will do about 50 write/read per second. Also what will be the best solution to broadcast message to all clients while they're connected to different servers. For example player X is connected to node 1, he do a simple action and how I can broqdcast the action to player Y which is connected to node 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be clustering across threads, then using Redis as your Socket.IO store is a perfect solution.

Redis is an extremely fast database, entirely run from memory, that can support thousands of publish/subscribe messages in a single second. Socket.IO has built-in support for Redis and when using it, any message emitted from one instance of Socket.IO is published to Redis, and all Socket.IO instances that have subscribed to the same Redis instance will also emit the same message.

This is how you would set up each Socket.IO instance:

```
var RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis');
var redis  = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis')

io.set('store', new RedisStore({
  redisPub: redis.createClient(),
  redisSub: redis.createClient(),
  RedisClient: redis.createClient()
}));
```

When Socket.IO is set up like this, and you have a Redis server, a simple `io.sockets.emit()` will broadcast to all clients on any server regardless of which server executed the code if all servers are publishing/subscribing to the Redis instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly redis is not that scalable as I read. Also I need to scale the project on multiple machines.

Comment: Redis **is** for scaling across machines. You can even set up master/slave instances of Redis with automatic failover.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually serialize the object into a JSON string and pass it as argument and de-serialize at each worker (num of CPUs).

Otherwise you can use `cluster.worker[<id>].send(<object>)` which will automatically take care of serializing/de-serializing.

For more information: Check [Node API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_worker_send_message_sendhandle)